# Bulk delete SharePoint lists

Tags: 2010, list, powershell, bulk

I have been scraping my head for a while thinking of what is the best practice for deleting a large amount of lists, approximately **8000** lists.

I have developed a PowerShell script that simply loops through a given web application Url for **empty** lists based on given list BaseTemplate id to delete them.

I've searched the web for some tips, came across [bulk operations](https://www.mavention.nl/blog/delete-items-batch-sharepoint-list-powershell-script) using **ProcessBatchData** towards list items, NOT the lists themselves!

What should I consider in my script? Should I take another approach?

All suggestions are welcome and if any further input is needed please let me know!

Comment: Embedding your script might help a little.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is generally nothing wrong with this approach and is fairly standard when dealing with operations across the farm in either PowerShell or server object models. Are you encountering any issues or performance problems?

An alternate method might be to leverage search to find all the lists, then iterate through them deleting each one.

Comment: Correct! It sounds like a less stressing idea to output the empty lists to a CSV file then loop the file and delete the lists accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Bulk Operations are against data.

In case of list you can simply use the Delete method associated with the list object. I am not sure how you are find the lists. I would prefer below approach

```
$webs = (Get-SPSite -limit all | Get-SPWeb -Limit all -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)  
if($webs.count -ge 1 -OR $webs.count -eq $null)  
{  
    foreach($web in $webs)  
    {  
        #Grab all lists in the current web  
        $lists = $web.Lists     
        foreach($list in $lists)  
        {  
            #check condition and delete
        } 
        $web.Dispose()  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Great Amal! Thanks for the input. My script is more or less the same as yours. :)